# Copy and paste when cell value is a certain text

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy and paste some values from column H into C, if G = "FUTURE".

```
Dim range1 As range
Dim cell As range
Set range1 = Sheets("Paste Port here - addFutureSDL").range("G:G")

For Each cell In range1
    If cell.Value = "FUTURE" Then
```

Comment: Please edit Your question to proper format. Meantime hint for You, iterate through cells base on variable, you can use it to offset /copy and paste in Your desirable destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you've selected whole column "G", better idea is to set last row of "G" and then iterate from 1 to last row.

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Paste Port here - addFutureSDL")

Start_row = 1
Dim Last_row As Integer
Last_row = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'finding last row (if used whole column "G" - can be deleted
Dim range1 As range
Set range1 = sht.range(Cells(Start_row, 7), Cells(Last_row, 7)) ' here u can change if u need to iterate through whole column "G" just to sht.range("G:G")

For Each cell In range1
    If cell = "FUTURE" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -4) = cell.Offset(0, 1) 'replacing
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Have a great day :)